# string split function in python

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, split

I am using : Python 2.6.6

I have the following sample code. scnd_dic.txt, contains Chinese char; I have problem with output of split. 
Is there any way to see Chinese char in the result of split instead of unicode?

print(line):            勀   KE4

print(line.split() ):   [u'\xe5\x8b\x80', 'KE4']

u'\xe5\x8b\x80' vs 勀;

```
import codecs
with codecs.open('scnd_dic.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:  

          #d = dict(line.rstrip().split(None, 1) for line in f)

          for line in f:

                 print(line)

                 print(line.split() )
```

in side scnd_dic.txt, there are some rows like following:

```
勀   KE4
垸   HUAN2
昇   SHENG1
洩   XIE4
犇   BEN1
缐   XIAN4
```

**Output:**

```
勀   KE4
[u'\xe5\x8b\x80', u'KE4']
垸   HUAN2
[u'\xe5\x9e\xb8', u'HUAN2']
昇   SHENG1
[u'\xe6\x98\x87', u'SHENG1']
洩   XIE4
[u'\xe6\xb4\xa9', u'XIE4']
犇   BEN1
[u'\xe7\x8a\x87', u'BEN1']
祕   MI4
[u'\xe7\xa5\x95', u'MI4']
缐   XIAN4
```

Comment: Are you using python 2? What is the desired output? "same output for split like reading lines" doesn't make sense to me, since the former is a string and the latter is a list.

Comment: I update the question

Comment: Is `print('[{}, {}]'.format(*line.split()))` what you want? Does it even work in python 2.6? It is a really old and unsupported python.

Comment: I bet the encoding is different in the file. If you do a `print(line.decode('utf-8').split()` do you get closer?

Comment: @AlG There aren't any encoding problems whatsoever as `print(['勀'])` shows (in python 2).

Comment: with trying print(line.decode('utf-8').split() , I am getting this error UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb7' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: The backslash escapes like `\xe6` won't go away when printing a list, unless you switch to Python 3. They are not an encoding problem, but rather the way Python 2 chose for displaying non-ASCII characters in the `repr` form. Have you tried Goyo's suggestion for constructing an output format yourself?

Comment: @goyo That's not my point. What encoding is the file and does the split need to translate it properly to keep it encoded correctly.

Comment: @AIG I know, but the OP shows that everything is properly encoded. Bytes are read from the file, then printed with `print(line)` and the expected caracters appear. `split` does not involve any encoding/decoding so it doesn't change anything. My example was mean to show that the same artifact appears whenever you print a list with non-ascii characters even if you make sure that everything is properly encoded.

Comment: thanks for your note I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue has nothing to do with unicode, encoding or decoding. You are seeing the hexadecimal representation instead of the actual character because that is how python 2 prints strings as items in a list when they have non-ascii characters. If you want to show the actual characters you need to bypass the mechanism for printing lists (read: do not print the list).

```
with codecs.open('scnd_dic.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:  
    for line in f:
        print(line)
        print(u'[u\'{}\', u\'{}\']'.format(*line.split()))
```

Output:

```
勀   KE4

[u'勀', u'KE4']
垸   HUAN2

[u'垸', u'HUAN2']
昇   SHENG1

[u'昇', u'SHENG1']
洩   XIE4

[u'洩', u'XIE4']
犇   BEN1

[u'犇', u'BEN1']
缐   XIAN4

[u'缐', u'XIAN4']
```